# UI Datepicker Limiting Days per month

Tags: angularjs

Below is my HTML code:::

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter date"
        uib-datepicker-popup="{{$ctrl.datePicker.format}}" ng-model="$ctrl.date" is-open="$ctrl.isOpened"
        datepicker-options="$ctrl.datePicker.dateOptions" ng-required="true" name="name" popup-placement="auto bottom-right"
        ng-click="$ctrl.openDatePicker($ctrl.date)" data-ng-model-options="{ 'debounce': 300}"/>
```

Controller code::

```
    $ctrl.datePicker = {
        format : 'MM-dd-yy',
        dateOptions: {
          dateDisabled: false,
          formatYear: 'yy',
          maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
          minDate: today,
          startingDay: 1,
          showButtonBar: false,
          altInputFormats: ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'],
          showWeeks: false,
          ngModelOptions: {
            debounce: 100
          }
        },
        isOpened: false
      };
```

I want to hide next month date which is not useful.

Comment: Thanks for formatting...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? a) Prevent the selection of _next_ months dates or b) prevent navigating to view the _next_ month, or  c) just not display the days after the last day of the selected month?

Comment: I'm trying to do number C. Hide days which is not included in the selected month.

Answer (score 0):

use         numberOfMonths: 1,
            endDate: '+29d'

Comment: I try but result not get it. Can you explain me more? Thanks.

Comment: putt this code in your controller and modify their attribute values according to your requirements. $(".form-control-calender").datepicker({
            startDate:'0',
            minDate:dateToday,
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            autoclose: true,

        }).on("changeDate", function (e) {
            var FromEndDate = new Date();
            var ToEndDate = e.date;
            ToEndDate.setDate(ToEndDate.getDate() + 90);
        });

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a class to the `customClass` property on the object that you pass to `datepicker-options`, so something like this:

```
$scope.options = {
  customClass: getCssClass,
  minDate: new Date(),
  showWeeks: true,
  // the rest of your options here...
};

function getCssClass(params){
  var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  var calDateMonth = params.date.getMonth();
  return (currentMonth !== calDateMonth) ? "hide-me" : "";
};
```

You may want to do further checks in the above function depending on the mode and the current month that is selected, but you get the idea of what is possible.

And then you just need the relevant class in your css file:

```
.hide-me {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xw0n61832zbjxaIc0lT8?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I click on next month it shows selected month last row. Can you please check and confirm.

Comment: @testertester Yeah I'm looking into it, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get the currently displayed date (rather than the currently selected date). It is possible to get the month from the DOM directly, but that isn't recommended as it would break as soon as someone changed the display formatting (not that they would, but the could!). Will have a think...